# Hive UDF class not found

Tags: java, hive

I need an auto-incrementing integer column in Hive and stumbled across [UDFRowSequence](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hive/trunk/contrib/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/contrib/udf/UDFRowSequence.java).

I created a Maven project in IntelliJ, added the `.java` file, and let the IDE import the dependencies. I then ran `mvn package`, copied the resulting `.jar` to a cluster node, and added the `.jar` resource in Hive:

```
hive> add file udf-row-sequence-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;
Added resources: [udf-row-sequence-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar]
```

Unfortunately, I'm unable to create the temporary function:

```
hive> create temporary function row_sequence as 'com.alexwoolford.hive.udf.UDFRowSequence';
FAILED: Class com.alexwoolford.hive.udf.UDFRowSequence not found
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask
```

And yet, if I look at the contents of the `.jar` file I can see that the class exists:

```
jar tf udf-row-sequence-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[...]
com/alexwoolford/hive/udf/UDFRowSequence.class
[...]
```

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by using `add file` instead of `add jar`, i.e.

```
add jar udf-row-sequence-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though you do "ADD JAR", sometimes even order of adding the JARS do matter, I faced this issue while adding ESRI Hive UDF jars.

```
add jar esri-geometry-api-1.2.jar;
add jar spatial-sdk-hive-1.0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar;
```

works

```
add jar spatial-sdk-hive-1.0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar;
add jar esri-geometry-api-1.2.jar;
```

Doesn't work